# Hogan.js: If-statements

Tags: javascript, html, templates, hogan.js

I have come to understand from the docs that Hogan doesn't support a lot of logic - yet there are some ways you can manipulate this templating system to do what you need.

Basically, this is what I need (in pseudo-code - given that the people.length >= 1):

```
{{#if people.length == 1}}
    <p>Your contact person is {{name}}.</p>
{{else}}
    <p>Your contact people are:</p>
    <ul>
    {{#people}}
        <li>{{name}}</li>
    {{/people}}
    </ul>
{{/if}}
```

Is this possible at all in the Hogan templating engine, or do I need to send in another variable telling whether or not there are exactly 1 member in my made-up people array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. There's no way to do this with Hogan without setting a different variable. This is one of the major shortcomings (in my opinion) of Hogan. I don't agree that "It's supposed to be logic-less" is a justification for this lack-of-feature. Both `if (true)` and `if (a == b)` are logic, but Hogan lets you do one and not the other. I agree that you shouldn't have logic in templates (because it can't be unit tested there), but Hogan/mustache goes too far toward this end. I recommend [swig](http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/) which gives you everything Hogan gives you, plus `if` comparisons, plus loop control (e.g. `if (loop.first)`), plus a nicer, easier to read filter syntax at only a very small performance hit (less than a second and a half over 100,000 templates according to [this](https://github.com/baryshev/template-benchmark), which, admittedly, is from a few years ago).

EDIT: Swig is no longer maintained; however, [Nunjucks](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/) is very similar to swig, both in scope and style.

Answer (score 0):

short awnser would be dont, its supposed to be logic-less

i just awnserd a question about a similar problem:
[Hogan.js - reference an item with a specific index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20103575/hogan-js-reference-an-item-with-a-specific-index)
pick one