# Hogan.js - reference an item with a specific index

Tags: javascript, mustache, hogan.js

I wish to have a section only for a particular item in an array. Eg:

```
var items = ['first','second']
```

Eg:

```
{{#items[1]}}
   Slightly different styling for the second item, for no difference other than it's the second item.
{{/items[1]}}
```

I've tried:

```
{{#items.1}}
  Slightly different styling for the second item, for no difference other than it's the second item.
{{/items.1}}
```

As well as:

```
{{#items}}
  {{#0}}
     Slightly different styling for the second item, for no difference other than it's the second item.
  {{/0}}
{{/items}}
```

But neither of those work.

I *really* don't want to have to make an object like:

```
{'1':'first','2':'second'}
```

Because that's just nasty.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

before i give you some suggestions/work-arounds
like you state, its just some silly styling, and as such has nothing to do with rendering or with the data. If it has a meaning in that sense you should realy add that to your data so it represents ts structure better.

Mustache is a logic-less templating language, and if you feel you need the Mustache language, you relaly should keep it as logic-less as possible, otherwise just use Handlebars

### css

you could use css 
 for that; [altho not in IE<9](http://caniuse.com/#search=nth-child) 
note the lack of the "n" in the filter

```
.selector:nth-child(2) {
    some: styling;
}
```

### change data

secondly, you could change the data before you pass it to Hogan
either as part of the data-processing in the controller or as the js frameworks sometimes call them view-controllers, 
changing it into an object is like you say not the best way, you could make it an array of array's

`[ [1,'first'], [2, 'second'] ]`

### Handlebars

if you dont need Hogan, Handlebars has an `{{@index}}` for the current index

### functions

as an alternative method to change your input data, you can create a helper function to handle that logic for you, but again this isnt really logic, its just visual. and mustache is a logic-less templating language, so be careful when starting with these kinds of

```
var items = ['first','second'];
var data = {items:items};

data.second= (function () {
    var i=0;
    return function () {
        return i++ === 1; //index 1 being the second item in an array
    }
}());
```

and then use the second helper

```
{{#items}}
    {{#second}}
    Slightly different styling for the second item, for no difference other than it's the second item.
    {{/second}}
{{/items}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer! I moved to express3-handlebars, which gave me the same features as hogan as was a drop-in replacement.

Comment: Trying it, I've actually realised Handlebars isn't a solution: {{@index}} is only for loops, I don't want to look, just literally have a section only for item 2.

Comment: @nailer and i just realized that you might mean you only want the second item from the list http://jsfiddle.net/LBNb8/ but not really flexible, just solve it outside the templates

Comment: thanks. Is there a way to create a helper that takes an argument? I don't want to create a new helper for each index.

Comment: @nailer sure http://jsfiddle.net/3X78P/ but then, why not just loop; if your worried about performance dont be, looping is most likely faster, compiling the template is most of the work

Comment: I can't loop. That's the nature of the problem. Eg, imagine you have a list of fruit. I want to show the third piece of fruit, in  the middle of some completely unrelated dinosaurs.